# archiving symlinks with python zipfile

Tags: python, zip, symlink, python-zipfile

I have a script that creates zip files of dirs containing symlinks. I
was surprised to find that the zipfiles have zipped the targets of the
links as opposed to the links themselves, which is what I wanted and
expected. Anyone know how to get zipfile to zip the links?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) doesn't appear to support storing symbolic links. The way to store them in a ZIP is actually not part of the format [and is only available as a custom extension in some implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#Implementation). In particular, Info-ZIP's implementation supports them so you can [delegate to it instead](https://serverfault.com/questions/265675/how-can-i-zip-compress-a-symlink). Make sure your decompression software can handle such archives - as I said, this feature is not standardized.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up forking off a subprocess to use the command line zip with --symlinks. It's much slower then the python zipfile lib, but it does support the symlinks.

Comment: @LarryMartell Info-ZIP has a shared library as well as a standalone executable which may save you some cycles. I cannot find any documentation for it though.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to have zipfile store symbolic links, instead of the files themselves. For an example, see [here](https://gist.github.com/kgn/610907). The relevant part of the script is storing the symbolic link attribute within the zipinfo:

```
zipInfo = zipfile.ZipInfo(archiveRoot)
zipInfo.create_system = 3
# long type of hex val of '0xA1ED0000L',
# say, symlink attr magic...
zipInfo.external_attr = 2716663808L
zipOut.writestr(zipInfo, os.readlink(fullPath))
```

Comment: python3 doesn't distinguish between longs and ints, so `zipInfo.external_attr = 0xA1ED0000L` should work (which is slightly more readable?)

Comment: I saw the better implementation: `zipInfo.external_attr |= 0xA0000000`

Comment: The magic constants are all available as well, e.g. `stat.S_IFLINK`

Answer (score 6):

Please find a complete Python code as a working example that creates a `cpuinfo.zip` archive with the symbolic link `cpuinfo.txt` that points to `/proc/cpuinfo`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import stat
import zipfile

def create_zip_with_symlink(output_zip_filename, link_source, link_target):
    zipInfo  = zipfile.ZipInfo(link_source)
    zipInfo.create_system = 3 # System which created ZIP archive, 3 = Unix; 0 = Windows
    unix_st_mode = stat.S_IFLNK | stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IROTH | stat.S_IWOTH | stat.S_IXOTH
    zipInfo.external_attr = unix_st_mode << 16 # The Python zipfile module accepts the 16-bit "Mode" field (that stores st_mode field from struct stat, containing user/group/other permissions, setuid/setgid and symlink info, etc) of the ASi extra block for Unix as bits 16-31 of the external_attr
    zipOut = zipfile.ZipFile(output_zip_filename, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zipOut.writestr(zipInfo, link_target)
    zipOut.close()

create_zip_with_symlink('cpuinfo.zip', 'cpuinfo.txt', '/proc/cpuinfo')
```

You can further issue the following commands (e.g. under Ubuntu) to see how the archive unpacks to a working symbolic link:

```
unzip cpuinfo.zip
ls -l cpuinfo.txt
cat cpuinfo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I have defined the following method in a Zip support class

```
def add_symlink(self, link, target, permissions=0o777):
    self.log('Adding a symlink: {} => {}'.format(link, target))
    permissions |= 0xA000

    zi = zipfile.ZipInfo(link)
    zi.create_system = 3
    zi.external_attr = permissions << 16
    self.zip.writestr(zi, target)
```

Answer (score 0):

While not part of the POSIX standard, many zip implementations support storing generic filesystem attributes on entries. The high bytes of the 4-byte value represent the file mode.

Essentially you need to replicate `ZipInfo.from_file`, but without following the link or truncating the mode:

```py
st = os.lstat(path)
mtime = time.localtime(st.st_mtime)
info = zipfile.ZipInfo(name, mtime[0:6])
info.file_size = st.st_size
info.external_attr = st.st_mode << 16
out_zip.writestr(info, os.readlink(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've tried to improve:

- tested with Python 3.11
- iterative loop instead of recursive.
- preserve the the original symlink attribute (e.g. permission)

---

```
import zipfile
import stat
import os 

def archive(source, output_path):
    def _convert_attr_to_symlink_type(external_attr):
        # Refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14727
        # zipfile external_attr is 32 bit file attribute structure
        # first 4 bits determine filetype
        # next 3 bit setuid, setgid, sticky
        # next 9 bit is the read write execute permission for user group & others.
        # next 8 bit is unused
        # last 8 bit is DOS attribute

        # Preserve everything except the first 4 bits (i.e filetype bit)
        # MASK: 00001111111111111111111111111111
        preserve_mask =  (1 << 28) - 1
        external_attr &= preserve_mask

        # Overwrite File type as Symbolic Link File type (modify first 4 bits)
        # MASK: 10100000000000000000000000000000
        overwrite_mask = stat.S_IFLNK << 16
        external_attr |= overwrite_mask
        return external_attr

    with zipfile.ZipFile(output_path, mode='w') as zf:
        for root, folders, files in os.walk(source):
            for folder in folders:
                folderpath = os.path.join(root, folder)
                if os.path.islink(folderpath):
                    zip_info = zipfile.ZipInfo.from_file(folderpath)
                    zip_info.filename = zip_info.filename.rstrip('/')
                    zip_info.external_attr = _convert_attr_to_symlink_type(zip_info.external_attr)
                    zf.writestr(zip_info, os.readlink(folderpath))

            for filename in files:
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)

                if os.path.islink(filepath):
                    zip_info = zipfile.ZipInfo.from_file(filepath)
                    zip_info.external_attr = _convert_attr_to_symlink_type(zip_info.external_attr)
                    zf.writestr(zip_info, os.readlink(filepath))
                else:
                    zf.write(filepath)


archive('testfolder', test.zip')
```